# Syntax correction of ERB using sublime 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2, code-formatting

I am tryimg to beautify my erb files. Some times I am getting "outdented too for on line" error. The error eliminates some of the line from my file and the remaining contents are saved with .html.erb.tmp extension.

**/home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:9:in `rescue in beautify': Error parsing abc.html.erb: Outdented too far on line 163 (RuntimeError)**

I came to know that it is as because of the alignment issues present in the .html.erb files. So I have decided to correct it first. For that I have installed sublime 2 plugin. Hereafter I would like to correct both html and erb syntaxes. I want to know how can I correct the syntax so that it can be beautified. what would be the best way to correct my erb files?

Answer (score 1):

try this gem 
https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier

Additionally: the gem above is presented as a [SublimePackage](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) but I did not manage to modify file using it

Comment: hmmm... I tested it on one erb view and it fixed it, but I did not use /test it a lot - so maybe the gem has some problems. Sorry.

Comment: It does not works for me. After adding beautify ruby some contents from my file is deleted